# SQLITE json_group_array ordering

Tags: json, sqlite

I am trying to get a nested JSON array in SQLite using the following query:

```
SELECT json_group_array( 
        json_object(
            'trip_id', t.id, 
            'trip_desc', t.desc,
            'trip_files', (SELECT json_group_array(json_object('file_id', f.id, 'file_desc', f.desc))
                    FROM files f
                    WHERE f.trip = t.id ORDER BY f.id ASC)
        )
    )
FROM trips t
WHERE t.year IN (SELECT id FROM years WHERE id=1)
ORDER BY t.id ASC;
```

Giving the following output:

```
[
    {
        "trip_id": 2,
        "trip_desc": "trip2",
        "trip_files": [
            {
                "file_id": 3,
                "file_desc": "file3"
            },
            {
                "file_id": 4,
                "file_desc": "file4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "trip_id": 1,
        "trip_desc": "trip1",
        "trip_files": [
            {
                "file_id": 2,
                "file_desc": "file2"
            },
            {
                "file_id": 1,
                "file_desc": "file1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can notice, the `ORDER BY` clause is being ignored. You can see the issue also in the following DBFiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bnjzbLUUoQFWAinMdQqovG/0

Any ideas on how to accomplish the ordering? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [aggregate functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) like `json_group_array()`, "If no `ORDER BY` clause is specified, the inputs to the aggregate occur in an arbitrary order that might change from one invocation to the next." Support for `ORDER BY` in an aggregate function was added in sqlite 3.44 (more recent than the version that db-fiddle is using (3.39 as of this writing)). The `SELECT`'s `ORDER BY` is irrelevant; it's the one in the aggregate function call that matters.

So you need a query like

```sql
SELECT json_group_array(
        json_object(
            'trip_id', t.id,
            'trip_desc', t.desc,
            'trip_files', (SELECT json_group_array(json_object('file_id', f.id, 'file_desc', f.desc) ORDER BY f.id)
                    FROM files f
                    WHERE f.trip = t.id)
        ) ORDER BY t.id)
FROM trips t
WHERE t.year IN (SELECT id FROM years WHERE id=1);
```

which gives (After running through a JSON formatter):

```json
[
  {
    "trip_id": 1,
    "trip_desc": "trip1",
    "trip_files": [
      {
        "file_id": 1,
        "file_desc": "file1"
      },
      {
        "file_id": 2,
        "file_desc": "file2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "trip_id": 2,
    "trip_desc": "trip2",
    "trip_files": [
      {
        "file_id": 3,
        "file_desc": "file3"
      },
      {
        "file_id": 4,
        "file_desc": "file4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

I noticed in testing an answer that with sqlite 3.44, `json_group_array(json expression ORDER BY expression)` converts the `json expression` part to a JSON string even if it starts out as some other type like an array or object, making it pretty much unusable. Sqlite 3.45, which features a complete overhaul of its JSON support, produces the desired results and is what was used to generate the above.